# How to create request scope with typescript-ioc

Tags: node.js, rest, typescript, express, inversion-of-control

Trying to have request scoped instances in my express app, using typescript-ioc, but I don't understand how custom scopes work in this thing.
How to does this work with @Scoped in typescript-ioc